# How to unhide taskbar on a maximized, non-resizable tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wanted my tkinter window to be maximized by default and nonresizable. However when I add the `root.resizable(0, 0)`, what happens is that the window overrides the taskbar. The taskbar is shown if I only add the `root.state('zoomed')` but when the `root.resizable(0, 0)` is added, it becomes hidden. Answers will be very appreciated.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame

root = Tk()

w = root.winfo_screenwidth()
h = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("%sx%s" % (w, h))

root.title("VNDB")
root.state('zoomed')
root.resizable(0, 0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: THIS QUESTION HAS ANSWERS HERE https://stackoverflow.com/q/73112195/13629335

Answer (score -1):

```
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

can you try this?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added it and it only made the whole window fullscreen. Now not only the taskbar is missing but also the "minimize, maximize, close" at the top unfortunately.

Comment: ```def resize(event):
    print("New size is: {}x{}".format(event.width, event.height))

root.bind("<Configure>", resize)``` You can add this to

Comment: Unfortunately nothing happened, it only showed this in the console:

New size is: 1366x768